AWSサーバにGNSS位置情報をPublishするコードでのエラー
Spresense Arduino チュートリアルにある AWSサーバにGNSS位置情報をPublishする のコードをテストしています。
APNやMQTT brokerの設定後に実行すると、APNへのアタッチは成功するのですが、下記のエラーがでて、MQTT brokerへの接続ができません。
MQTT connection failed! Error code = -1

このエラーの修正方法があれば教えていただけないでしょうか？
宜しくお願い致します。

こちら見てみましたが、
arduinoのspresense3.2.0とMQTTライブラリのArduinoMqttClientの0.1.8の利用で、接続はできています。
一部ログ

・・・
Attempting to connect to network.
Gnss setup OK
Waiting for successfull attach.
attach succeeded.
・・・
Attempting to connect to the MQTT broker: ** endpoint name **
You're connected to the MQTT broker!
Position is not fixed.
・・・

BROKER_PORTをデフォルトの8883から、443などに替えると同じエラーとなりました。設定したMQTT周りのパラメータは正しいでしょうか？　もしお使いのパラメータでAWSへの接続実績がなければ、例えばspresense-SDKのlte_awsiotのexampleなどを使って、AWSIOTに接続できることを確認して、問題を切り分けることもできるかと思います。
